# Azure WebService - MySQL - Redis configuration

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am creating a WebService with C# Core 3.0 that is using MySQL and Redis, but I am not so familiar with Azure so I need advice about configuring everything.

I had MySQL hosted on AWS, but I am transferring it to Azure because I think that performance (speed) will be better on Azure because they will be on same data center. Right?

But, on my MySQL page Host is like `'*.mysql.database.azure.com'`. That means that every connection will go out of Azure, and than come back? I don't have some local IP for connection? Same question for Redis.

Do I need to configure some local network on Azure and will that impact speed on the app? And, is MySQL a good choice for Azure or should I try with another one?

I am just reading about Azure Virtual Networks. But as I understand it, VN's sole purpose is to isolate elements from the outside network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get better performance if your my-sql instance and your app service are in the same region (basically the same data centre).

The connection string is mysql.database.azure.com, but remember the connection will be a TCP/IP connection, so the DNS lookup will realise that this address mysql.database.azure.com is in the same region (same data center). Then the TCP/IP connection will go to an internal IP.

You could use tcpping in your app service's kudo console to try this and see the result.

The basic rule is that you should group your app and database in the same region for better performance and cheaper cost (as Microsoft doesn't charge traffic within the same region).

Azure Virtual network is for a different purpose. For example, if you have some on premise database servers and you want to call these servers from azure, then VM could be helpful. But for the scenario you described, it is not really needed.

The company I work for has Microsoft azure support included, and if you or your company have support contract with them, you can raise questions directly to them and get really quick responses.